# powershell new-psdrive not mapping drive

Tags: powershell

New-PSDrive doesnt seem to work in a script block when submitted as a job, it works fine interactively as a scriptblock.

This works as a normal interactive script block:

```
$getcred = Get-Credential 'myuser'
$servers = "myserver"
$jsession = New-PSSession -ComputerName $servers -Credential $getcred
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {
New-PSDrive -name share1 -psprovider FileSystem -root \\server\directory;
dir share1:
};
```

This doesn't mount the drive:

```
$getcred = Get-Credential 'myuser'
$servers = "myserver"
$jsession = New-PSSession -ComputerName $servers -Credential $getcred
$job = Invoke-Command -Session $jsession -AsJob -Jobname 'testjob' -ScriptBlock {
New-PSDrive -name share1 -psprovider FileSystem -root \\server\directory;
dir share1:
};
Wait-Job $job
$r = Receive-Job $job
$r
```

Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'share1' does not exist.

It seems the security context is not being transmitted on the session ?

Comment: You're certain that the original example worked outside of the job?  The issue should be as mentioned in my answer, and happen with or without the job.  The problem should be the double hop of the invoke-command, not the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, you're using the credential for creating the connection to the remote computer, but the session itself is not using a token capable of making a second-hop.  The session is using what's known as a Network Login.

You indicate that the New-PSDrive within the Invoke-Command works fine when not used as part of a job - but please verify that.

Try this line in your scriptblock - note the addition of the `-Credential` to explicitly map the drive as the same user you connected the session with.

```
New-PSDrive -name share1 -psprovider FileSystem -root \\server\directory -Credential $using:getcred
```

You can also address this with [CredSSP](http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2014/03/06/accidental-sabotage-beware-of-credssp/), but that has other security implications and is not necessary for a simple remote file share access.

Passing a credential this way to a remote server should still only be used with servers you trust.

Comment: I can confirm 100% that the first example in my posted question works and the second section does not work.  I will try adding the $using on the end.

Comment: You may have a previously mapped drive on the remote server, that already had the explicit credential mapped. I'm not quite sure how the job would interfere with that, but I'd suggest calling `get-psdrive` and `get-smbmapping` before mapping your PS drive to see what, if anything, is pre-existing.

Comment: no it wasnt that, was trying on a brand new server never connected before.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `-Scope Global` flag.

According to docs:
"PSDrives are created in the scope in which the New-PSDrive command is run. When the command is run within a script, the drive mapping is local to the script. When the script exits, the drive is no longer available."
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-psdrive?view=powershell-7.3#example-6-create-persistent-drive-in-a-script

Answer (score -2):

You are trying to run multiple command in a row.

```
invoke-command
```

Is for running a single command at a time.

To establish a persistent connection to a remote computer (Executing multiple command in a row) use:

```
Enter-PSSession
```

In case you still want to use your version of the script, hers how it should be done

```
$getcred = Get-Credential 'myuser'
$servers = "myserver"

$jsession = New-PSSession -ComputerName $servers -Credential $getcred

$job = Invoke-Command -Session $jsession -ScriptBlock { New-PSDrive -name share1 -psprovider FileSystem -root \\server\directory }
$job2 = Invoke-Command -Session $jsession -ScriptBlock {dir share1:}

$job
$job2
```

Comment: Thats not true Invoke-command can have several commands as above in my first working example.  I need to execute a series of a few commands in a row using a file on a network object on many computers.  The AsAJob should be ideal as it does it in the background.  Your example fails the same as my second part, but I know it isnt permission based problem as my first example works.

Comment: I dont see a foreach or any begin process end in your script example.

Comment: This answer is not correct. `Invoke-Command` can run entire scripts, and `Enter-PSSession` is specifically for an _interactive session_ not for a persistent connection (which the poster correctly used `New-PSSession` for).

Comment: Can you post the full version ?

Comment: Error is Access is denied
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (\\server\directory\:String) [Get-ChildItem], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ItemExistsUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
    + PSComputerName        : server

Comment: YanivK, as briantist states, Invoke-Command can be used to run multiple commands, I dont want to use Enter-PSSession as thats for interactive work.  The Invoke-Command can perform your commands or if they are going to take a long time I should be able to submit the scriptblock as a job so they run in the background.  What I am stating is that when the same scriptblock is run as a job in the background the New-PSDrive command doesnt work, it doesnt mount the drive, net use is empty.

Comment: I am only trying to help you. 
The behavior that you see is actually by design and is referred to as the Kerberos “second hop” problem.  Please research Credential Security Service Provider (CredSSP).

Comment: I understand credSSP needs to be setup to access network locations, but I dont believe it is needed for New-PSDrive to work.  My first example of using it with Invoke-Command works fine, it is only when New-PSDrive is used by Invoke-Command with the -AsJob to run in background that it fails.  I wonder if CredSSP is needed when running AsJob ?

Comment: Found an article for you : https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2012/11/14/enable-powershell-second-hop-functionality-with-credssp/

Comment: Thanks.  I will enable it and see in then New-PSDrive works in background.  If it works all I can assume is as I thought it isnt passing on your credentials to it when you run it in background.

Comment: Richard, any progress ?